# shell get parse arguments

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to use my shell script like this:

```
myscript.sh -key keyValue
```

How can I get the **keyValue** ?
I tried `getopts`, but it requires the `key` to be a single letter!

Comment: It's much simpler to do `key=keyValue myscript.sh` and just reference the variable `$key` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

use a manual loop such as:

```
while :; do
  case $1 in
    -key)
      shift
      echo $1
      break
    ;;
    *)
      break
  esac  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `getopts`:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
    -key)
        case "$2" in
        [A-Za-z])
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Argument to $1 must be a single letter."
            exit 1
            ;;
        esac
        keyValue=$2
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid argument: $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

If your shell is `bash` it could be simplified like this:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    -key)
        if [[ $2 != [A-Za-z] ]]; then
            echo "Argument to $1 must be a single letter."
            exit 1
        fi
        keyValue=$2
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid argument: $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think it's well worth learning getopts: you'll save lots of time in the long run.

If you use getopts then it requires short versions of switches to be a single letter, and prefixed by a single "-"; long versions can be any length, and are prefixed by "--". So you can get exactly what you want using getopts, as long as you're happy with

```
myscript.sh --key keyValue
```

This is useful behaviour for getopts to insist on, because it means you can join lots of switches together. If "-" indicates a short single letter switch, then "-key" means the same as "-k -e -y", which is a useful shorthand.